Is Firefox's about:license non-compliant wrt. MIT and BSD style Licenses?
The Firefox (ref: V 127.0.2 on Windows) License Page about:license diligently lists all potential open source licenses involved.
In an attempt to make this mess shorter, the devs have opted to group identical licenses and just list the components for the licenses. See eg: about:license#bsd2clause
However, for MIT and BSD-x-Clause licenses, they "only" reproduce the license text, without the copyright header, when the license clearly states (BSD 2/3 clause):


Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.


Several contributing components for these licenses are Rust or C++ code where source is not included in the binary distribution, and so isn't the original LICENSE file(s) that contained the Copyright line for said components.
So, it would appear that Mozilla is not exactly compliant with these licenses because they explicitly  require attribution of copyright, which apparently is not done in current Firefox versions.
Would best practice indicate that Mozilla should be more diligent with their attribution, am I missing something or is this a non-issue?

Please Note:
Personally, I don't care, nor do I hold it against Mozilla, iff above is indeed literally in violation of these licenses. Mozilla certainly seems to try to honor the spirit of the redistribution requirements of its components. And of course it is rather trivial to find the Copyright online.
However, I am tasked with generating an attribution report for our proprietary product, that will, unfortunately, be checked by 3rd party lawyers and therefore I'm trying to be as nit picky as possible.


So, it would appear that Mozilla is not exactly compliant with these licenses because they explicitly require attribution of copyright, which apparently is not done in current Firefox versions.

I agree with your analysis. Mozilla should be more diligent with their attribution to fully comply with the licenses.
In practice, it may be a non-issue based on how interested the authors of those MIT/BSD licensed components are on having their name mentioned, but that consideration is unlikely to convince lawyers doing an audit.
